# How to have node id value set depending on some other id?

Tags: 7, nodes, cdn

I have database table which I need to import it in drupal database (basically create a node for each row of database table ) .
 The non drupal database has mim Id .
I want to create a node which would have the mim Id == node id 
So in all, how can I achieve such that Drupal's ID node will be SAME as article ID (this ID is used in an external media CDN server).

I tried looking at the CDN module but could not find a solution for the same

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) and [this hands-on guide](http://www.gizra.com/content/data-migration-part-1/) (disclaimer: I work for that company, so to balance: [lullabot's guide](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/drupal-data-imports-migrate-and-table-wizard) ) Both are good to understand everything that's necessary for what you asked.

You might want to consider creating a `field_old_node_id` field to ease on the transfer if you can't set the ID through this, and use [Pages module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) to create a separate `/node/%nid` page that uses that field instead to display the node.